# Change DES master key to AES in Mifare Desfire

Tags: android, encryption, nfc, delphi-xe7, mifare

I want to change DES master key to AES key on Mifare DESFire Ev1 cards. I am using Delphi (XE7) and I wrote our communication protocol in native commands. I have too completely datasheet (under NDA NXP). Could you write some steps or function, that I have to use? I have already function for change key (only DES). I know these information is under NDA, you can contact me on mail: jiri.grigar@gmail.com

Comment: I don't think the idea of the NDA is to privately exchange documents/code with other parties.

Comment: Its all very detailed in the MF3ICD81 document, if you need examples get the Features and Hints Document (AN0945), if you have questions contact your NXP supporter. The case you are searching for is the exact example in 9.1.4 in AN0945

Comment: Maarten Bodewe : I know, but i did not find example of this problem. @Paul Bastian : Thanks for advice. I have not document AN0945, but now I send request to NXP. I have only MF3ICD81 document, which describe change key only with specific cipher but not between ciphers (or I did not find it).

Comment: Read carefully, it's in there. Can't help more than that

Comment: @Paul Bastian : Thank you very much. Yes, it is there, but I needed some example, which describe construction of data to send. It is better described in 9.1.4 AN0945, which I have already now. It works fine.

Comment: Isn't this what i wrote exactly in my first comment??

Comment: Maarten, do you see ANY sense in hiding documentation? Isn't it the MOST stupid thing to sell RFID cards and not give documentation for them? Do you really think that a malicious person who tries to crack Mifare systems is not able to obtain that information?? Didn't the Mifare Classic desaster show clearly that "security through obsucrity" does not work? How is it possible that a company still thinks that they can hide infromation in the age of Wikileaks and Edward Snwoden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is described in document AN0945 in section 9.1.4